# ID3 Tags Injection equivalent for RTSP (Android)

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp

I know for Apple HLS, we can inject ID3 tags into the stream.
Can this be done for RTSP (Android) or anything equivalent to it? Or rather, how would I be able to accomplish the equivalent of injecting dynamic ID3 tags into the stream via RTSP (Android).

Thanks.